# Symfony output only template--without adding to layout.php

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, link-to

Is there any way to disable the addition of `layout.php` to my `actionNameSuccess.php`? I would like this setting to be enabled for some modules and disabled(i.e. let `layout.php` add up) for other modules.

I can solve the problem by making a new application and setting its `layout.php` to just

> `<?php echo $sf_content?>`

but I would like a same-application solution. Since  I need to have links between these two and link_to only works relative to an application and I don't want to pass an absolute url.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can call `$this->setLayout(false);` in your action. I think you may also achieve this with the `view.yml` file.

**UPDATE**: as denys281 pointed out, the way to do this in `view.yml` is to use

```
has_layout: false
```

Comment: In view.yml you can make: `has_layout: false`